# why actor module not support concurrent mailbox?

Tags: akka, mailboxer

I'm fresh to akka, also actor,I wonder why can't find a concurrent mailbox to use.
As a result, I must define a dispatch actor send to its work actor.Many times, I not care about data's sequence and in this situation make message by sequence just cost time.

Comment: AFAIK Akka default mailbox is concurrent and with out-of-order semaantics

Comment: Consider using a Router. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/routing.html#simple-router-scala

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio, not concurrent point at message's consume always one  by one.thanks your tips

Comment: @ViktorKlang, I have seem the Router, its manager its rountee actor and seems good at dispatch message.Maybe a good choice.BTW,Could we define a router like mailbox in actor straightly?

Comment: Read the docs I linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find create actor with Router props is good choice:

```
val actorRef: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor]
        .withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 4)), name = "myActor")
   //or 
context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[MyActor]), "myActor")
```

It will create four actor instance but return one actorRef -- `RoundRobinPool` handle and dispatch message to these actors.